# comparing two list and choose the max and min. (float is not a interable object)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, mean

I have two lists (Kelloggs and general_mills), with their respective means as you can see and I need to compare and get what is the max and min between them.

I'm gonna show you my code and the error on it.
[image]

Please, help me to fix it.

Comment: Provide dataset so that we can debug

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `max` function gives you from a list or an array of numbers the maximum. You can't apply the `max` function to a not iterable object (a list or an array with more than one element).

`mean1 + mean2` is one number. just as 3 + 4 = 5 for example. You can't take the `max(5)` it will throw the same Error.

You want the maximum between `mean1` and `mean2` therefore you should not add them, just change the last line to `print(max([mean1, mean2]))`

Comment: Thanks!!
I just solved it with your help!

Comment: `max(mean1, mean2)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find a max in a sum of elements.

##### The max function have this format:

```
max(N1,N2,..,Nm)
```

##### So you need to separate the items for those who need to find the max value:

```
max_value = max(mean1, mean2)
print(max_value)
```

That portion of code should should be work